# How to the find the sum of a specific multi dimentional array value?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array, sum

I have an associative array, which have 'question', 'maxmark', 'qpno'. ( *This is Post request data of a Form submission.* )

```
array (size=3)
'question' => string 'Question one' (length=12)
'maxmark' => string '5' (length=1)
'qpno' => string 'QB345' (length=5)

array (size=3)
'question' => string 'Question two' (length=12)
'maxmark' => string '10' (length=1)
'qpno' => string 'QB345' (length=5)

array (size=3)
'question' => string 'Question three' (length=12)
'maxmark' => string '5' (length=1)
'qpno' => string 'QB345' (length=5)
```

I have a variable, `$total_mark = 25;`

I want to add all the 'maxmark' from the multidimentional associative array and check If it is equal to `$total_mark`;

```
if( sum of all maxmark = $total_mark ) {
do this
} else {
do something else
}
```

Please Help.

Note: No of arrays in the multidimentional array varies. Also maxmark is a "string".

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use `array_sum()` and `array_column()`:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array(
      'question' => 'Question one',
      'maxmark' => '5',
      'qpno' => 'QB345'
    ),    
    array (
      'question' => 'Question two',
      'maxmark' => '10',
      'qpno' => 'QB345'
    ),    
    array (
      'question' => 'Question three',
      'maxmark' => '5',
      'qpno' => 'QB345'
    )        
);

$total_mark = 25;
$sum_mark = array_sum(array_column($array, 'maxmark'));

if ($total_mark == $sum_mark) {
    //
} else {    
   //
};   

?>
```